Unknown component identification (SMD Marking L43 stacked 10)
What is this component? I need to replace it. How to get replacement.?
Some info I found indicates BAT54C, but do the stacked numbers mean anything?


Up-vote because you included all the needed information.

They also need to include dimensions, if they are asking where to buy it that is off topic.

It's a Panjit BAT54CW Schottky diode.


(Source: lcsc.com)


Do the stacked numbers mean anything?

It's probably a date code or lot number.

How to get replacement?

Buy any BAT54CW diode. LCSC alone has 24 different manufacturers listed for this diode.

Thank you for the information and the time taken to answer the question.
